# Many links , multiple GET[]

Tags: php, html, get

I Am currently writing My first big project.

I have a navbar with many links that now are linking to "index.PHP?a=value&b=value"

On My index page i have the following:

```
if((($_GET['a']) == "value") && (($_GET['b']) == "value")) {
     *** soms code ***
}
if((($_GET['a']) == "value") && (($_GET['b']) == "value2")) {
     *** soms code ***
}
```

Etc...

But with 50 are more links My index.PHP file Will get a Little bit clutterd.

I have thinking of changing the code to:

```
if((($_GET['a']) == "value") && (($_GET['b']) == "value")) {
     include("somefile.php");
}
```

Wat is the best way to go around this ? Maybe the onclick=.. ?

Please your thoughts on this

Comment: There's probably a better approach to what you are trying to do.  What's the practical use of `a` and `b` in your url? What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: so values can be both "a" AND "b", or "a" OR "b"?

Comment: "index.php?a=client&b=edit" or "index.php?a=client&b=mail" or "index.php?a=supplier&b=new" and so on....

Comment: it sounds like you're trying to implement your own router. I would avoid that if possible because there are already lots of nice ones you can choose from

Comment: @FuzzyTree What do you mean by router ?

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify like that

```
if ($_GET['a'] == "value") {

    if ($_GET['b'] == "value") {
         *** soms code ***
    } elseif ($_GET['b'] == "value2") {
         *** soms code ***
    } elseif ($_GET['b'] == "value3") {
         *** soms code ***
    }

    // ...

}
```

or if you want to have your code in more files, try this :

```
if (    isset($_GET["a"])
    &&  isset($_GET["b"])
) {
    // security : cut all but a-z
    $a = preg_replace("![^a-z]!", "", $_GET["a"]);
    $b = preg_replace("![^a-z]!", "", $_GET["b"]);

    // include the file
    include "files/part1-$a-part2-$b.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You write a big project. Why don't you use a serious framework as Laravel, etc? That make it less complex for you to make a scalable and maintainable application.

Separate routing from your index. Separate responsibilities (presentation, business logic, etc.)

Read more about effective routing in Laravel: http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#basic-routing

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem solved long ago. In modern frameworks it is called routing, you can look it up.

A simplified example would be to have an array mapping values to files on the system, and then call a function to include the appropriate file.

```
$routes = [
    'value1' => ['value1' => 'file1.php'],
    'value2' => ['value2' => 'file2.php']
]

function route($value1, $value2) {
    global $routes;
    require($routes[$value1][$value2];
}
```

Then in index.php you just call

```
route($_GET['a'], $_GET['b']);
```

*This example is not to be taken literally, it is just an illustration*

As suggested in another answer, it is probably a good idea to consider using a framework. They exist for a reason.